# OpenVMS joining CIFS as domain member fails

Tags: samba, openvms

I'm unable to join a new VMS server as a member of our Windows AD domain.  It's an Integrity RX2800 running OpenVMS 8.4.  There are two existing VMS servers joined that work fine.

Using SMBCONFIG I get the following output when it attempts to join:

```
Joining CIFS Server as MEMBER to domain FOO...

Unable to join domain FOO
The failure message reported by the net command is:

[2017/08/25 09:03:25, 0] SAMBA$SRC:[SOURCE.LIB]UTIL.C;1:(1181)
  gethostname failed
[2017/08/25 09:03:25, 0] SAMBA$SRC:[SOURCE.LIB]UTIL.C;1:(1181)
  gethostname failed

Previous configuration files have been restored.
```

I've had trouble finding relevant results on Google, can anybody here help?

Edited to add:
Here is a complete console log of the setup process: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/BJs7d3x9)

Comment: Can you specify the domain controller IP/hostname when connecting? If you can, try that. i.e. net -S

Comment: As part of the SMBCONFIG script, it asks for a PDC emulator name and confirms it can connect, so it is specified.

Comment: Did you enter it as hostname or IP?

Comment: The script specifically asks for hostname.  I was having a DNS issue earlier and it couldn't resolve so it followed up by asking for IP specifically.  Now the DNS issues is resolved and it only asks for hostname.